# Does Qt QSettings keeps the key/value in memory once loaded?

Tags: c++, qt, settings

im using QSettings to write to ini file and loading the configuration in application start 
my question is once i load value by key does QSettings object keeps the key value in memory 
or its reads the value from the ini file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are handled in memory, so changing the file doesn't change the QSettings object you have in memory and vice versa.

edit:

Call *sync* to update to/from file.

It saves values you have modified and reads any values you didn't modify but were modified in the file.

example

```
// settings.ini contains keys Hello and Hi, which contain both "-"

QSettings settings("settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat),

// in settings object: *Hello* contains *-* and *Hi* contains *-*   
// in settings.ini: *Hello* contains *-* and *Hi* contains *-*

settings.setValue("Hello", "World");
// settings.ini is modified, Hi now contains World

// in settings object: *Hello* contains *World* and *Hi* contains *-*   
// in settings.ini: *Hello* contains *-* and *Hi* contains *World*

settings.sync();

// in settings object: *Hello* contains *World* and *Hi* contains *World*   
// in settings.ini: *Hello* contains *World* and *Hi* contains *World*
```

Or that's how it should work if I remember correctly

---

out of the qt (5.10) docs to QSettings::sync() - This function is called automatically from QSettings's destructor and by the event loop at regular intervals, so you normally don't need to call it yourself.

– lumos0815

Comment: where changes are also written in the QSettings destructor.

Comment: so i dont need to write Config singletone to hold my configuration in memory i can use the QSettings object created once

Comment: It seems that they are updated on the destructor http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qsettings.html   
@user63898 If i understood correctly, yes.

Comment: out of the qt (5.10) docs to QSettings::sync() - This function is called automatically from QSettings's destructor and by the event loop at regular intervals, so you normally don't need to call it yourself.

Comment: My answer is 7 years old. There was no sign of Qt 5 back then :) But thanks for telling me this information, I'll update the answer.